# Force images to have same height in same row of Google MDL grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

First time using MDL and I've worked out a lot with [the grid](http://www.getmdl.io/components/#layout-section/grid), but I'm having trouble with getting two header images to show up at the same height.

In the top row of the site, I'd like to have a long, banner-like image at top left, and a square profile photo image next to it, followed by some text for a company or portfolio name.

Here's what that top row looks like:

```
<div id="container" class="mdl-js-layout mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400">
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--hide-tablet mdl-cell--hide-phone">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
        <div class="header-text">HEADER TEXT</div>
        <div class="bio-text">SUBHEADER TEXT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: [Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/893exoww/).

The placeholder images are deliberately larger than they would ever display, as the container is limited to a width of 1200px.

For some reason, when I do this, the second, square image shows up with a shorter height than the first, banner image, no matter how wide the viewport is.

Some suggestions I've found via search have involved flexbox, the properties of which appear to already be incorporated into MDL, but I tried adding it on top anyway without success -- although I'll admit that I'm not absolutely sure I did that correctly.

I appreciate any help anybody can offer.

UPDATE: I solved it by making the first image a background image of its div, since it will likely be a landscape or some other type of environmental image. It's not a perfect solution, so if somebody else has a thought, I'm still open to suggestions. But here's what I did in the meantime (in production, the style is separate, but I'm including it here as shorthand):

```
<div id="container" class="mdl-js-layout mdl-grid">

    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet" 
style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/1200x400); 
background-size: 100%"></div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--hide-tablet mdl-cell--hide-phone">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
        <div class="header-text">HEADLINE</div>
        <div class="bio-text">SUPPORTING TEXT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle would be helpful since not all of us use mdl

Comment: Thanks. Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/893exoww/